# How to cache images with Picasso having dynamic URL?

Tags: android, picasso

I'm dynamically downloading images into list view using Picasso library. It works fine but when URL of image is changed then image is re-downloading again. So my question is how to cache images with dynamic URL? Maybe it's possible to set id for image and make it as primary key for Picasso instead of url?

Comment: You can only override cache functionality while create your own class extending from Picasso(for example with tag usage). But i will recommend you use other library with cash key customization